# Open pdf with window open not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm using below code for open pdf in window.open for dynamic title of pdf.

This code is working fine but in Chrome browser it is not working.

I am seeing title of pdf when open but pdf not open.

```
function titlepath(path,name)
{
  var prntWin = window.open();
  prntWin.document.write("<html><head><title>"+name+"</title></head><body>"
  + '<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="'+path+'" '
  + 'type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="21"></body></html>');
  prntWin.document.close();
}
```

Comment: There is no jQuery in your question. I retagged it and removed jQuery from the question. It is plain JS. Do you get any errors in the console, for example if you are on HTTPS and the PDF is on another origin or using HTTP

Comment: What is the `'type="application/pdf"` doing on the embed? Also try using an iFrame instead

Comment: check if any warning is throwing by the browser in the address bar ?

Comment: @mplungjan No there is no any error. But when open pdf in new window it is just this "about:blank" in url.

Comment: Can you open pdf on your chrome? try to open any other pdf to see if it's something related to your chrome setting

Comment: @tomerraitz There setting of chrome is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming same protocol and possibly same origin

***NOTE:*** Assuming PDF is from a website too since you may get issues loading from file system

***NOTE:*** If the server sends [x-frame-options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options), you may not be allowed to show it

Try an iFrame

```
function titlepath(path,name) {
  var prntWin = window.open("");
  prntWin.document.write("<html><head><title>"+name+"</title></head><body>" + 
  '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="'+path+'"></iframe></body></html>');
  prntWin.document.close();
}
```

or at least close the embed

```
function titlepath(path,name) {
  var prntWin = window.open("");
  prntWin.document.write("<html><head><title>"+name+"</title></head><body>" +
  '<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="'+path+'"></embed>'+
  '</body></html>');
  prntWin.document.close();
}
```

Comment: Hello this code is working fine in mozila but not working in chrome browser same as with my code.

Comment: Chrome doesn't allows loading local resource if you are doing that.

Comment: @mplungjan Not working. I also add this code on server but same issue with server also.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options